# Data received through serial in Python

Tags: python, split, text-processing, strip

I have configured on Raspberry Pi UART and this is my serial reading / writing code:

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 9600, timeout=1)
ser.open()
string = '#SET0\r\n'
print string
ser.write(string)
bytes2read = ser.inWaiting()
print bytes2read
if (ser.inWaiting()>0):
  incoming = ser.readline()
  print incoming
time.sleep(5)
bytes2read1= ser.inWaiting()
print bytes2read1
if (ser.inWaiting()>0):
  print "Data:"
  cont = ser.read(bytesaleer1)
print cont
```

cont has this format:

```
#D0:0:0:10
#D1:0:0:56
#D2:0:0:23
#D3:1:1:90
--------
```

My question is, How can I get and save the last 0 on that variable? I want to save in c0,c1,c2,c3 values obtained from cont; 10,56,23 and 90.
Have tried with line.strip but with no good results.

Comment: `int(cont.split(':')[-1])`

Comment: int(cont.split(':')[-1])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0\r\n--------\r\n'

Comment: Then `int(cont.split(':')[-1].rstrip('\r\n-'))`

Comment: Folks, read the problem first. How is `cont.split(':')[-1]` going to produce four values from different lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `cont` is a string containing all five lines of text, including the `--------` separator line, I'd start by splitting it into lines:

```
cont.splitlines()
    => [ '#D0:0:0:10',
         '#D1:0:0:56',
         '#D2:0:0:23',
         '#D3:1:1:90',
         '--------' ]
```

Then you can loop over all the lines, and *if* the line includes a colon, pull off the last value and save it.

```
vals = []
for line in cont.splitlines():
    if ':' in line:
        v = int(line.split(':')[-1])
        vals.append(v)

>>> vals
[10, 56, 23, 90]
```

Comment: Working like a charm with your code Tim Pierce , really thanks.